# How to get at RadioButton in SubItem of ExpandableListView - Android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

How can I get at my custom RadioGroup within my subitem in my ExpandableListView when the current view is just main layout view showing below:
I have- mainListView.xml //expandableListView 
      - group_row.xml    //textView 
      -child_row.xml     //has custom radioButton

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.mainListView);

      ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
      SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
                new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                        R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.
                        new String[] { "Group Item" },  // the key of group item.
                        new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.
                        createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                        R.layout.child_row,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                        new String[] {"Sub Item"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                        new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
                    );
                elv.setAdapter(expListAdapter);       // setting the adapter in the list.

        }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
        }


    answersGroup = (SegmentedRadioGroup) findViewById(need this from child_row); 
    answersGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you extend your SimpleExpandableListAdapter class and do override

```
@Override
getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

to obtain the viewgroup?

Comment: I ended up doing this, not sure if its alright. final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        final View childview = factory.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
       
        answersGroup = (SegmentedRadioGroup) childview.findViewById(R.id.answersGroup);